# How to delete remain data in WP database after deleting custom post via admin interface

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin that will delete pictures and additional info from database on deleting custom post (sp_venue) via admin panel (wp-admin/edit-tags.php)

In the plugin I'm using this to catch the event:

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'kg_delete_post' );

function kg_delete_post($postId) {

    $post = get_post($postId);

    if ($post->post_type != 'attachment') {
        return false;
    }

    $url = str_replace($dirs['baseurl'],'',$post->guid);
    $urlParts = explode("/",$url);
    $numberOfParts = sizeof($urlParts) - 1;

    $dirs = wp_upload_dir();
    $fileNameParts = explode(".", $urlParts[$numberOfParts]);
    $fileName = str_replace('.' . end($fileNameParts), '', $urlParts[$numberOfParts]) . "-*." . end($fileNameParts);
    $path =$dirs['basedir'] ."/".  $urlParts[$numberOfParts-2] . "/" . $urlParts[$numberOfParts-1] . "/";
    $fullPath = $path  . $urlParts[$numberOfParts];
    $fullPathSearch = $path . $fileName;

    @unlink($fullPath);
    foreach (glob($fullPathSearch) as $filename) {
        @unlink($path . $filename);
    }
}
```

It works with:

`wp_delete_post($Id, true)`

But looks like the event on deleting via admin panel is no the same.

What should i use to make it works?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding my js on in admin panel to customize the click on delete button.